# Are there any nonland Plains?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

There's a card called [Emeria Shepherd](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Emeria%20Shepherd) that reads (among others, emphasis mine)

> *Landfall* - Whenever a land enters the battlefield under your control, return target **nonland** permanent card from your graveyard to your hand. If that card is a **Plains**, you may return that nonland permanent card to the battlefield instead.

Is there a nonland permanent card that is a plains?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are not any cards that are non-land and a Plains. This is because each type has their own list of subtypes that can be associated with them and Plains is a land subtype. Cards cannot have subtypes that don't match one of their types, therefore it is impossible to have a card that is a Plains but not a land.

> **205.3d** An object can’t gain a subtype that doesn’t correspond to one of that object’s types.
>
> **205.3i** Lands have their own unique set of subtypes; these subtypes are called land types. The land types are Desert, Forest, Gate, Island, Lair, Locus, Mine, Mountain, Plains, Power-Plant, Swamp, Tower, and Urza’s.
> Of that list, Forest, Island, Mountain, Plains, and Swamp are the basic land types. See rule 305.6.

---

Also as had been mentioned the second sentence of the Shepard's ability should be *"If that **land** is a Plains, you may return that nonland permanent card to the battlefield instead."* referring to the land that triggered the ability in the first place, not the card you target in your graveyard.

Comment: Is it me, or has this ruling not yet been updated to be in line with the new addition of "Wastes".

Comment: @LaurensSwart 'Wastes' is not a land subtype, it is just the name of a card that has no subtypes. The mana producing ability is given through oracle text not the land's subtype like all other basic lands.

Answer (score 9):

Your text is slightly off.  It's actually:

> Whenever a land enters the battlefield under your control, you may return target nonland permanent card from your graveyard to your hand. If that **land** is a Plains, you may return that nonland permanent card to the battlefield instead.

So, it's referring to the land that triggers landfall, not the nonland permanent you're targeting in your graveyard.

Comment: Maybe "It's referring to the land that triggers landfall..."

Comment: Wow, I read that card so many times and always got it wrong :D

Answer (score 2):

@JonTheMon points out how a misinterpretation of the card's text led to your question. However, the literal answer to your question is no, there are no nonland plains (shown in [this query](http://magiccards.info/query?q=t%3A%22plains%22&v=card&s=cname)). All 13 cards with the subtype *Plains* also have the type *Land*.

Comment: Plains is a subtype, and Land is a type.

Comment: @HaoYe Good catch. Fixed.